# How to remove top bar of Windows Connect?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-10-v1809, miracast

After updating to the Windows October 2018 Update, I have this bar at the top of my screen when I'm using Connect to cast to another screen:
[image: Bar saying "Connected to Surface-Pro-3" at the top of the screen]

This is after unpinning it, but it still appears when I move my mouse to the top of my screen, which is pretty annoying when I want to switch tabs in Google Chrome or click on other things at the top of the screen. I can drag it around to different positions at the top of the screen, but not to any place else. I don't think this bar was there before updating to the October 2018 Update.

I don't see any settings in Settings > System > Projecting to this PC regarding this.

Is it possible to remove it entirely?

Answer (score 3):

I actually had to use `Alt`+`F4`

Comment: Alt-F4 closes programs. It doesn't make a connection bar go away.

Comment: That's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Then you're either ending the screen share process, which OP didn't want to do, or you're ending some other process that isn't involved at all.

Answer (score 2):

yes, click on it like if you will drag/move then in keyboard do: ctrl + F4 and it will close.

cheers!